# When I insert any data on any table, I should look at that record top in list view using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have shown two different table record in the same view but when I insert data to any table so I should look at that record top in list view. I don't know how to do that. Can I use one loop for two different tables?

**Controller**

```
                        public function index()
                        { 
                        $data=[
                       'Digitizingorders'=>Auth::user()->digitizing()->get(),
                       'Vectororders'=>Auth::user()->vector()->get()
                        ];
                        return view('front_end.profile.tool.pendingorders',$data);
                        }
```

**HTML view**

```
                      <tbody>
                      @foreach($Digitizingorders as $key=> $Digitizingorder)
                      <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>DON-0{{$Digitizingorder->id}}</td>
                      <td>{{$Digitizingorder->order_name}}</td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>{{$Digitizingorder->recieved_date}}</td>
                      <td>{{$Digitizingorder->released_date ?? 'processing'}}</td>
                      <td>$0.00</td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                      @foreach($Vectororders as $key=> $Vectororder)
                      <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>VON-0{{$Vectororder->id}}</td>
                      <td>{{$Vectororder->vector_name}}</td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td>{{$Vectororder->recieved_date}}</td>
                      <td>{{$Digitizingorder->released_date ?? 'processing'}}</td>
                      <td>$0.00</td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                      </tbody>
```

Comment: so if a record is inserted into DigitizingOrder, all of the DigitizingOrder records will show before VectorOrder or only the new record?

Comment: I want an only new record of any table on top .

Answer (score 0):

To make new items display on top I think you have to order by date created_at  like adding

`->orderByDesc("created_at")->get()`

```
public function index() {    
         $data=[ 
          'Digitizingorders'=>Auth::user()->digitizing()->orderByDesc("created_at")->get(), 
         'Vectororders'=>Auth::user()->vector()->orderByDesc("created_at")->get()
         ]; 
    return view('front_end.profile.tool.pendingorders',$data); 
    }
```